# animation: edit the way an object moves by grabbing the pose in the curve editor or graph editor

Tags: animation, dopesheet, graph-editor

A Maya user asked me if it is possible to do this in blender: slow or accelerate a movement, rotation, etc. by grabbing a frame (not necessarily a keyframe) into the timeline, the graph editor or the dope sheet, and Maya automatically creates a new keyframe.

In blender you can go to any frame where the wanted pose is, insert a keyframe and then move it to the wanted location, but in Maya you can do it by a single click (grabbing the frame where the wanted pose is, to a different location in your timeline) which saves a lot of time when you are animating and need to test different times and speeds.

there is a way to do this in blender? I mean, the one single click stuff? thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

In the graph editor and dopesheet you can press <kbd>I</kbd> to insert a keyframe just like in the 3dview. You will get a menu to choose between all or selected channels.

In the graph editor with a key selected you can press <kbd>G</kbd> to move it, also pressing <kbd>Y</kbd> will keep it locked to the frame so you only change the value. You can drag an existing key with the mouse to adjust it's value, the drawback of using the mouse is you need to drag the mouse some distance to start the movement, at which time the key snaps to the mouse location making small accurate adjustments hard without the keyboard.

Once you select a key in the graph editor you can move it more precisely using the keyboard eg. <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>.5</kbd>

You also have the properties panel <kbd>N</kbd> in the graph editor that shows the frame and value of the active key, you can use the mouse to drag the value slider.